# how to read files in folder in ascending order?

Tags: c#

i have folder that contain image files which named with number 1,2,3...
 how do i read the image file name in sequence starting with 1 until the end(whatever number it is).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) on file array.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\yourfolder");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
//User Enumerable.OrderBy to sort the files array and get a new array of sorted files
FileInfo[] sortedFiles = files.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToArray();
```

For File number with **just numeric(int) names** try:

```
FileInfo[] sortedFiles = files
                          .OrderBy(r => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r.Name)))
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: This will order acc to text. ie. 1,10,11...2,20 like that. You should convert it to integer and then ordery by.

Comment: How about `r => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r.Name))`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, It will raise exception because of the file extension

Answer (score 2):

Habib's answer is correct, but note that you won't get the results in numerical order (i.e. you'll process 10.png before you process 2.png).  To sort the filenames numerically, instead of alphabetically:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
         .OrderBy((f) => Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f1))))
{
    // do something with filename
}
```

Comment: that what i want to do, i want to read the files in numerical order because the all the files name is in numerical format.

Answer (score 1):

Read all filenames into an array. Sort the array elements in ascending order. Done!

Answer (score -2):

Collect all the file names inside the directory using Arraylist and sort them (It also appicable for alpha numeric file names

```
        ArrayList <String> dirFiles=new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File("DirectoryPath");

        File createdFile = null;
        String [] str=file.list();
        for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++){
            dirFiles.add(str[j]);               
        }

        CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator();
        Collections.sort(dirFiles, comparator);
        for(String fileName: dirFiles){
                 Console.println(fileName);
         }
```

Comment: Console.Writeline is what you're looking for.  And there are much simpler ways to accomplish this in c#