# vb.net Order of reading all files from folder

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

I have issue with order of reading all files from folder.

My code read files with wrong order
when I have files:
1.txt
2.txt
10.txt
20.txt
100.txt

my code read files look at first letter of file:
1.txt
10.txt
100.txt
2.txt
20.txt

how can I read file with numerical order?
1.txt
2.txt
10.txt
20.txt
100.txt

I use code on the below:

```
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(Path), fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim strplik As FileInfo
        For Each strplik In fiArr
        'read strplik from file
        next strplik
```

Comment: Those arent numbers, they are test so `9.txt` will be "higher" than `1000.txt`.  You need to sort the results using a Natural Sort [such as the one here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786276/1070452)  Also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Here's a nearly identical question https://stackoverflow.com/q/12907499/5162073

Comment: so is there any method without sorting names of files?

Comment: @JakubM : Nope.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the filenames as string you can sort the files in the following way

```
Dim files as String() = {"1.txt", "10.txt", "15.txt", "2.txt", "20.txt"}
Dim sortedResults = from file in files _
                    order by file.PadLeft(10, "0") _
                    select file
For Each result in sortedResults
    Console.WriteLine( result )
next
```

What it will do, is make sure that all the files have a total length of 10 chars, by adding 0 in front of the text, in the end, you will get something like

```
1.txt  => 000001.txt
10.txt => 000010.txt
```

This way, it will be sorted alfabetically correctly, another option is to convert to int but, I don't see the necessity for it here

A full example can be found in this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ltiUF)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the filename, **without the extension**, consists of only a numeric value, then you could do:

```
Dim files = New DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles.OrderBy(Function(x) Val(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)))
For Each file In files         
    Debug.Print(file.FullName)
Next
```